# How to listen on a future stream in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to listen to a future stream and I am running into an error. I have tried everything and yet the error returned is;

> The method 'listen' isn't defined for the class 'Future'. Try
>   correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
>   method named 'listen'.dart(undefined_method)

How do I accomplish this?

```
Stream<AdventuresState> _mapLoadAdventureToState() async* {
    _adventureSubscription?.cancel();
    try {
      _adventureSubscription = _adventureRepository.getAdventures(_profileID).listen(
            (adventure) => add(
              AdventuresUpdated(adventure),
            ),
          );
    } catch (error) {
      AdventureError("Error: $error");
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like you're confusing streams with futures. The return type of _mapLoadAdventureToState is unclear to me too. Could you please elaborate better?

Comment: In my AdventureRepositoryImpl I have a method where I need to check if there is a network connection. So I need to await for this. As its asynchronous, I have to make it a future. But doing this now creates an error with my listen method in my bloc class.

Comment: Why don't you `await _adventureRepository.getAdventures(_profileID)` ? Or alternatively use `_adventureRepository.getAdventures(_profileID).asStream().listen`.  I'm confused too, you're not yielding anything?

Answer (score 1):

**Receiving stream events as Future**

The asynchronous for loop (commonly just called ***await for***) iterates over the events of a stream like the for loop iterates over an Iterable.

```
Future<AdventuresState> _getSingleStep(Stream<AdventuresState> adventureStream) async {
    await for (var adventure in adventureStream) {
      return adventure;
    }
}
```

Source: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this you want to do?

```dart
Stream<AdventuresState> _mapLoadAdventureToState() async* {
  final adventure = await _adventureRepository.getAdventures(_profileID);
  yield AdventuresUpdated(adventure);
}
```